# Problems using the UpdateProgress control

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, asp.net-3.5

I've inherited a web application which heavily uses Anthem.net. There is one operation which is acting slow and I've been asked to add a loading icon to signal the user that information is being fetched.

I started working on using the asp:updateprogress control which works normally on the page with asp:updatepanel. But when the trigger controls are located in a anthem:panel control then the loading icon isn't displayed, like it isn't recognizing the callback mechanism

I've noticed that for a button in asp:updatepanel then the following javascript is rendered:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnGaman" value="Gaman" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnGaman&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="btnGaman" />
```

But for a button located inside anthem:panel:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Leita" onclick="javascript:Anthem_FireCallBackEvent(this,event,'btnSearch','',true,'','','',true,null,null,null,true,true);return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnSearch&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="btnSearch" class="button darkgrey px52" />
```

Is there some javascript tweak that i'm missing for anthem and asp:updateprogess to work normally together ? or should I use some anthem control to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I ended up with removing the [Anthem.Net](http://anthem-dot-net.sourceforge.net/) usage in my page altogether and opted using asp:updatepanel instead. I did this mainly because the [Anthem.Net](http://anthem-dot-net.sourceforge.net/) project seems to be no longer maintened, so I swapped it out :) Took a lot of work, but I think it will be better in the long run

Answer (score 0):

You can override the desired control in anthem classes as I did for example for Literal.